# wanting a thunar action to install .deb packages. Have lxqt-sudo

Tags: thunar-custom-actions

I'm looking for an action that works.
I've tried
lxqt-sudo apt-get install %f
but it won't work, not even show for other files

thunar 1.18.4
Xubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom action in Thunar file manager to install .deb files manually as follows. This custom action is better than `lxqt-sudo apt-get install %f` because it tries to install any .deb file's required dependencies too.

1. Open Thunar's preferences and select *Edit*- -> *Configure custom actions*.
2. Add a new action by clicking the **+** button.
3. Configure the action.

   ```
   Name: "Install .deb package with apt."  
   Command: sudo apt install ./%f  
   Applies to: *.deb
   ```
4. Click  <kbd>OK</kbd>  to save the action.

If this doesn't work install the *thunar-custom-actions* extension. This extension includes a predefined action called "Install with APT". Once installed and applied, right-clicking a .deb file will show this option alongside other choices.